# TYPO3 v9.5 URL Segment [slug] generation for a record shall not prepend the page slug

Tags: typo3, slug

Is there any possibility to modify the automatic slug generation for a record in the TYPO3 backend list module in a way that the page slug of the sysfolder is not prepended?

The extension configuration adds the slug field in a way that the slug for the record should be generated by the fields title and itemnumber. This works fine on one TYPO3 9.5 website, but it does not work on the other.
The extension file is here:

https://github.com/franzholz/tt_products/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tt_products.php

The current sysfolder page has this slug:

```
URL Segment: abc
```

The current record has these data:

```
Title name: product 1
itemnumber: item1
```

The automatically generated slug will be:

```
abcproduct-1-item1
```

The wanted resulting slug is:

```
product-1-item1
```

Where is the configuration to change the behaviour that the sysfolder **page slug is not prepended** any more during the slug's auto generation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The TCA of the table must be changed in this way: **prefixParentPageSlug=false**

```
'generatorOptions' => array (
    'fields' => array ('title', 'itemnumber'),
    'fieldSeparator' => '-',
    'prefixParentPageSlug' => false,
    'replacements' => array (
        '/' => '',
    ),
),
```